# Text looks thinner after rotation

Tags: tikz-pgf, rotating

I want to rotate math text at 45 deg for a picture, but the text looks thinner. Here is a small piece of code with the same text, one "un-rotated" and the other rotated by 45 deg.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{amssymb} %maths
\usepackage{amsmath} %maths
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node at (0,0) {$f_1-f2$};
\node[rotate=45] at (1,1) {$f_1-f2$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Do you know what is wrong ?

[image]

Comment: Is it? http://i.stack.imgur.com/fY4w5.png I don't think so.

Comment: Didn't notice a thinner looking text. What viewer do you use?

Comment: I use sumatrapdf. It looks same for me.

Comment: I am using LatexIt to have a first draft of my picture, and then I compile under TeXShop (for mac). In both case, it looks thinner. I added a picture in my previous message.

Comment: @Basil: Did you make a print of that part and compare the `thickness` of the output?

Comment: What happens if you open the ouput pdf with `preview app`? Here on evince it they seem identical to me.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, you're actually right. It's just my perception. I opened the picture in Photoshop and it's a perfect match. My bad...

Answer (score 4):

This is most likely a font rendering issue in your PDF viewer. Your viewer probably has a specialized rendering algorithm for horizontal (unrotated) text.

When you print the document, the two text pieces should look identical. Maybe it is already enough to just open it in a different program.